# Adding Document to a record library programmatically

Tags: 2010, object-model, records-management, records-center

I have a requirement, where I need to upload a document like invoice report to a record library programatic. I have used the same code as uploading document to a normal document library. Now the requirement is when I am uploading a same document again, I am getting the error as

```
The file is checked out for editing by SHAREPOINT\system.
```

Whereas when I am uploading existing document to a record library from the Sharepoint UI. It automatically renames the record(infact adds some random string at the end of the orginal file name). Is there a way, where I can achieve without writing lot of code? Looking for any sort of help.

Comment: I have tried, but that was for normal document library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last after so much of research, I have found a solution. Create an intermediate Document library and upload document. Route the document to the record center. Check out the sample code.

```
string strFilename="Name of the File uploaded";
Hashtable metadata=new Hashtable("Other Meta data columns");
bool IsOverwrite="True or False to overwrite the existing file";
byte[] by_FileStream="Array bytes of the uploaded file";
bool MoveToRecordCeter="True or False To move to record center"; 
string strSPSite="<Site URL>";
string strSPRecLib="<Intermediate Doc Lib>";
string RecordCenterUri="<Record Center URL>";
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strSPSite))
{
    SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
    string strAdditionalInformation = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        SPList oList = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(strSPRecLib);
        if (oList != null)
        {
            SPFolder oFolder = oList.RootFolder;
            SPFile oFile = null;
            oFile = oFolder.Files.Add(oFolder.Url + "/" + strFilename, by_FileStream, metadata, IsOverwrite);
            oFile.Update();
            if (MoveToRecordCeter && RecordCenterUri.Length > 0)
            {
                string Offuri = RecordCenterUri.Trim();
                SPOfficialFileHost ofh = new SPOfficialFileHost();
                ofh.Action = SPOfficialFileAction.Move;
                ofh.OfficialFileName = oFile.Name;
                ofh.OfficialFileUrl = new Uri(Offuri);
                OfficialFileResult returnValue = oFile.SendToOfficialFile("Content-type", ofh, "", SPOfficialFileSubmissionMode.ExpirationPolicy, out strAdditionalInformation);
                if (returnValue != OfficialFileResult.Success)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error sending file to records center:" + strAdditionalInformation);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("List is not available.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (oWeb != null)
            oWeb.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Hope this would help some one :)

Comment: BTW, There should be an additional note. I user who is moving the document to a record center(programatically) must be a member of Record Center Web Service Submitters. This is must :)

Answer (score 1):

suryakiran, you need to undeclare the existing record before overwrite the file.

```
SPList recordList = recordWeb.Lists.TryGetList(recordLibName);

SPFile recordFile = recordWeb.GetFile(recordFileUrl);
if (recordFile.Exists && Records.IsRecord(recordFile.Item))
{
    Records.UndeclareItemAsRecord(recordFile.Item);
}

SPFile newRecordFile = recordList.RootFolder.Files.Add(
    sourceFile.Name, sourceFile.OpenBinary(), true);
```

Comment: Please add details to your answer, think for yourself, would you find this answer helpful in its current form? :) Code and / or links is often very helpful