# Route a document to a Record Center using Client Object Model

Tags: web-services, client-object-model, records-management, records-center

I need to programatically upload a document and route to the record center with all content organizer rules. This should be a Client Object Model Solution. I have a solution in Server Object Model. But not sure how we can achive the same in Client Object Model. This link would show how to route using server object model.

[Adding Document to a record library programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/adding-document-to-a-record-library-programmatically)

Can anybody help me on this Please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a Solution, though not a very convincing one. Create a Custom WCF service which uses the same functionality defined in the Server Object Model Solution and deploy the same under _vti_bin folder. Following the procedure provided in the below MSDN link and solve the issues

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same requirement, instead of writing a web service, I'm looking at using the built in [[MS-OFFICIALFILE]: Official File Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313141%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The SubmitFile method on this should ensure the document is routing when the document is submitted (it's how SharePoint routes documents between sites itself).

Comment: Yes, I have looked into it. But couldn't able to understand. Thought instead of wasting time, we can get a solution quickly. Could you please share the procedure, if you have any :)